How to start a minimal Wayland session from command line?
A way to debug X is that I start an X server (X -ac :0), then an xterm (DISPLAY=:0 xterm) and a WM on it (DISPLAY=:0 icewm).
It is unthinkably useful is there is a display problem.
What can I do with wayland? I absolutely do not want a full gnome, I just want a terminal and a VM - and see from the error output, if anything is bad.
I would also miss dbus, if possible.

Wayland doesn't have a notion of a "clean display server", it's part of your desktop environment.
You could try running mutter directly from your Linux console (Ctrl + Alt + F2) though and then try to launch any graphical terminal emulator, e.g. gnome-terminal:
mutter &
WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0 gnome-terminal

Or wayland-1.

Right but that is not so easy - there is also some XDG_DIRECTORY or what. Beside that, my direct experience is that yes, wayland has a central server, called weston (probably mutter is another), it also has window managers, like sway. I am lesser and lesser sure, why should we throw out X. What I can say for nearly sure, if I used a linux years long and then I do a dist-upgrade, then I won't have X.

Weston is a sort of demo. It's not "central" to anything. It's not even the most full-featured Wayland implementation, KWin is. Mutter is close second. All the rest are grossly underdeveloped. There's an extremely long thread about this topic here: https://gist.github.com/probonopd/9feb7c20257af5dd915e3a9f2d1f2277 Probably well over 6K messages.

Okay. To my last knowledge, kwin was the window manager of the kde. Are these the same things? Btw, I think the initial part of the text is mostly not true. Beside that, compatibility until the eternity will only kill us all. I remember ggi... and I am whining on the future of the open source world.

You're correct about Kwin. Under X11 you had the Xorg server which could run by itself and allow to run any applications of combinations of them. A WM under Xorg is optional. Wayland merges the display server with the window manager, it's now a single piece of software.

Okay thanks! So, then kwin is now also a wayland server? So, I start kwin and then I can target it with WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0 with any wayland-capable app, incl. firefox?

You're correct on all accounts.
